# Log from multiple python files into single log file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have multiple python files, I need to log from multiple python files into a single common log file. I dont want to use the log configuration file for formatting or json dictionary. Each of the python files are imported into a master python file kickstart.py and they are all called from kickstart.py. I want to log all messages from various python modules called from master python script into a single log file. 
Please suggest methods do it. i went through python cookbook but that was not helpful.I am very new to this.

Thanks

Comment: Did you read [the docs about logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html)?

Comment: I read the documents and I am not sure why it works with logger(somename) but not with logger(__name__)
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html example here

Answer (score 8):

You can do that using the `logging` module. Define this function in one of your base modules, and call it in every module you would like to log something.

```
import logging
def get_logger(name):
    log_format = '%(asctime)s  %(name)8s  %(levelname)5s  %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format=log_format,
                        filename='dev.log',
                        filemode='w')
    console = logging.StreamHandler()
    console.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    console.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(log_format))
    logging.getLogger(name).addHandler(console)
    return logging.getLogger(name)
```

Then from every module you want to log from, call this function with the logger name you want, and all your modules would print to the same log file defined by the `filename` argument.

```
<base.py>
logger = get_logger('base')
logger.info('testing logger from module base')

<module2.py>
logger = get_logger('module2')
logger.info('testing logger from module module2')

<dev.log>
2017-08-11 00:34:00,361     base   INFO  testing logger from module base
2017-08-11 00:34:00,361     module2   INFO  testing logger from module module2
```

[logging.basicConfig()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)

Comment: Hi @Chen A.  Thanks It works well Thanks; I also tried it. But if my filename is Dynamic Like; 

filename=f"Dev_+{datetime.now().strftime('%m_%d_%Y_%H_%M_%S')}.log"

then it creates two separate log files. any suggestions please to get logs in Single File

Answer (score 2):

@Chen's answer is right. I'm providing a specific use case as follow:

Say you have two python files `py1.py`, `py2.py` that you want to import to your master file `master.py`.

```
#py1
import logging
def fun1():
    LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    LOGGER.info('fun1 runs')

#py2
import logging
def fun2():
    LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    LOGGER.info('fun2 runs')

#master.py
import py1
import py2
import logging
def main():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='log.log',level=logging.INFO)
    LOGGER = logging.getLogger("main")
    py1.fun1()
    py2.fun2()
    LOGGER.info('Master runs')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then executing `master.py` will generate one single `log.log` file that contains logging from all modules (`py1.py` and `py2.py`).

Comment: How will this example look if I'd like to use logging.FileHandler instead of basicConfig?